# Android Fragment data flow

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a simple application where i would be able to enter and show some data.

I have MenuActivity which contains only FrameLayout,and on onCreate method of MenuActivity it gets populated with MenuFragment that contains 2 buttons.

First button will get me to EntryFragment in which I enter some data and pass it back to MenuActivity(by implemented interface) and put it in a List.

Second button will get me to ListFragment which is actually RecyclerView.
ListFragment is created by ListFragment.newInstance(List list).

But when i enter some data in EntryFragment and then click back button I will be in MenuFragment.If I then open my ListFragment it wont be populated with the my data.

I've made it work by making MenuActivity List static, and then when creating a ListFragment i just pass that static list.

I really doubt that it is the right way to do it.
So what is the right way to do it?
Should i really recreate MenuFragment(and pass List from MenuActivity and then pass that data when creating ListFragment) every time i enter some data?
Or am i missing something about fragments?

Comment: What I would do : send the EntryFragment's data to the main activity and get them in the ListFragment from there.The main activity is the app's central point, so it seems logical to let it collect each and every "global" data (i.e data common to different Fragments).

Answer (score 0):

While opening EntryFragment from MenuFragment, You can set the TargetFragment as MenuFragment So that you can pass the callback directly to  `MenuFragment` and you can save there.

Now you have the data in MenuFragmnet So it will be easy to handle the data between `Activity` and the `ListFragment`

Try to read about [`Fragment.setTargetFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)) and `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult`